# Mockito, mock and change Calendar.getIstance()

Tags: java, spring, calendar, powermockito

### How can i mock and Change time?

I use Calendar.getInstance() inside the Method under test

this is the method

```
 public List<Object> chechAuth(){
    Calendar from = Calendar.getInstance();
    if(jobService.findJobByCheckAuth(from.getTime(), true).isEmpty()){
        from.add(Calendar.YEAR, -10);
    }
    Calendar to = Calendar.getInstance();
    to.add(Calendar.MONTH, 2);
    
    System.out.println("from: "+from.getTime());
    System.out.println("to: "+to.getTime()); 
    
    return objectDAO.findAuth(from.getTime(), to.getTime());
}
```

when I use Calendar to = Calendar.getInstance(); it return a date different from July 02 2016

This is my test class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) 
@PrepareForTest({Calendar.class, ImpServiceTest.class})    
public class ImpServiceTest {

@InjectMocks
private ImpService impService = new ImpServiceImpl();

@Before
public void setup(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    now.set(2016, Calendar.JULY, 2 ,0,0,0);
    
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Calendar.class);
    PowerMockito.when(Calendar.getInstance()).thenReturn(now);
}

@Test
public void methodTEST() throws Exception {
    
     Calendar from = Calendar.getInstance();
     when(jobService.findJobByCheckAuth(eq(now.getTime()), eq(true))).thenReturn(new ArrayList<Job>());

     impService.chechAuth();
  }
```

this code print

> From: Sat Sep 02 00:00:00 CEST 2006
>
> To: Sat Sep 02 00:00:00 CEST 2006

I want that the first Calendar.getInstance() return

> Sun Jul 02 00:00:00 CEST 2006

and the second

> Fri Sep 02 00:00:00 CEST 2016

some advice?

Answer (score 3):

You should annotate the test class with:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Calendar.class, MyTest.class})
```

Where `MyTest` is the name of the class with tests.
For powermockito to work you need to prepare for tests both the class being mocked as well as the target class.

I'm not sure if it is possible to prepare for tests the test class, so if it doesn't work move the Calendar code to other class.

Comment: no ... it doesn't work

Comment: Normally you need to prepare for test also the target class, so in this case it would be the test class name.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
@Test
public void methodTEST() throws Exception {

PowerMockito.mockStatic(Calendar.class);

    Calendar from = Calendar.getInstance();

   Date time = from.getTime();
```

Mockito.when(Calendar.getInstance()).thenReturn(from);

Mockito.when(from.getTime()).thenReturn(time);

```
    System.out.println(from.getTime());

    from.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);

    System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
  }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: `Mon Jul 04 11:52:20 CEST 2016

Sat Jul 04 11:52:20 CEST 2015`
This is result of your test, i want to get that the second line is now.

Comment: but you have already modified from by 1, can you please share whats the exact requirement

Comment: I have modified answer a little bit, can you check and confirm if it solves the purpose

Comment: I changed my question... some advice? my goal is use on methodUnderTest 2 different variable using Calendar.getInstance() and i want change that dates