# Getting NotAMockException on Calendar.getInstance() mocking

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, powermockito

I am trying to mock `Calendar.getInstance()` for unit testing purpose.

I am thus using PowerMock (`powermock-core:2.0.4` & `powermock-module-junit4:2.0.4`) and its Mockito API (`powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.4`).

I am well aware that similar cases [do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275840/java-how-to-mock-calendar-getinstance) [exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38148077/mockito-mock-and-change-calendar-getistance?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I am facing an exception that does not seem to appear on other's case.

Indeed, when doing

```java
mockStatic(Calendar.class);
when(Calendar.getInstance()).thenReturn(aCalendar);
```

on a test method within a class annotated  with

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({DateUtils.class})
```

I get the following error : `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: Argument should be a mock, but is: class java.lang.Class`.

What did I do wrong and how to solve it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues here.

`mockStatic(Calendar.class);` this should be in setUp method or something.

Then you do this.

```
verifyStatic(Calendar.class)
when(Calendar.getInstance()).thenReturn(aCalendar);
```

Another important thing is the following,

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({DateUtils.class, Calendar.class})
```

Any class that has static method you would like to mock should be included in @PrepareForTest either at the class level or method level, if it is used only once.